# /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php Magento Script edit

Tags: magento-1.7, php, html

I'm reasonably new to Magento and i'm trying to edit my Magento code/script (what ever you call it) and all the forums keep telling me to

"Copy /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php to /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php." to be able to access it

My question is where the hell is this and where do I enter it?

Probably a very silly question but I'm having a blonde day.

Comment: By default magento has only `core` and `community` inside app/code. You need to create `local` folder. Then place the file inside that.

Comment: Never, ever, copy a class file to the local code pool to override it. This is an antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question for:

> /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

Copy to :

> /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

Which means that you have to create the same folder structure in your local, we do it in order to avoid over riding the core files. This is done while upgrade som of the core file are modified so that your customization is not updated.

For more info on how to over ride core files in Magento refer to this [LINK](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_a_local_copy_of_app_code_core_mage)